# Kanji in Latin1_General_CI_AI collation table

Tags: sql-server, collation

we have an application in production from several month. The db (SqlServer 2008) has Latin1_General_CI_AI as default collation .

Now we have been asked to introduce japanese language. Is there any issue or drawback using japanese characters with this collation?

Of course all text fields are nvarchar.

Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default katakana and hiragana are treated as the same.

This will influence the sort orders and comparisons.

If you need to have katakana and hiragana treated differently, you might want to use a collation ending with _CI_AI_KS. So you can use Latin1_General_CI_AI_KS.

- CI - Case insensitive
- AI - Accent insensitive
- KS - Kana sensitive